# how to calcule a rank of a tensor in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image `A [300 300 13]` that i presented as a tensor in order to extract characteristic via this tensor.

```
Tensor T = (A);
```

I have trouble understanding the interest of decomposition (either Tucker or CP) to the tensor decomposition why this decomposition ?
and how to calculate the rank of the tensor??

Comment: How about `rank(t)`? From the [docs]...(http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rank.html)

Comment: I already try rank (T) and this gives me this error : Undefined function 'svd' for input arguments of type 'tensor'.

Comment: What's with the C(++) style variable declaration?

Comment: How about `numel(size(A))` ?

Comment: @Carl witthoft this still does not give what we want

Comment: In that case you need to provide more details. In particular, what doyou consider to be the tensor rank?  I'm using the strict algebraic definition.